# Preventing package installation on ARM processors

Tags: arm, wix, windows-installer

I'm tinkering with an installer for keyboard layout drivers (derived from MSKLC), and, just like any other drivers, these are architecture-specific, thus I want to prevent users from installing them on incompatible computers.

When it was just x86, x64 and Itanium, it was relatively easy to detect. A block like this in the `wxs` file:

```xml
<?if $(sys.BUILDARCH) = x86 ?>
<Condition Message="!(loc.UnsupportedPlatformMessage)">Not Msix64</Condition>
<Condition Message="!(loc.UnsupportedPlatformMessage)">Not Intel64</Condition>
<?endif ?>
```

would prevent the x86 version from installing on x64 and Itanium, and the installers for the latter two platforms would automatically fail on x86 (as well as on each other, presumably) due to the lack of platform compatibility/emulation.

However, when ARM and ARM64 come to picture, things seem to get a bit more complicated: Windows Installer doesn't appear to [define any ARM-specific properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference#hardware-properties) I could check for, and ARM64 Windows installations support both x86 and x64 emulation. The block above still makes the x86 installer fail early (because `Msix64` is defined), but so far I haven't found a way as simple as this to make the x64 installer fail on ARM64.

So far I've come up with the following block and a call to the `ResolveCpuArchitecture` Custom Action before `LaunchConditions` are checked:

```xml
<?if $(sys.BUILDARCH) = x86 ?>
<Property Id="TargetArchitecture" Value="X86" />
<Launch Condition="NOT VersionNT64" Message="!(loc.UnsupportedPlatformMessage)" />
<?endif?>
<?if $(sys.BUILDARCH) = x64 ?>
<Property Id="TargetArchitecture" Value="AMD64" />
<?endif?>
<?if $(sys.BUILDARCH) = arm64 ?>
<Property Id="TargetArchitecture" Value="ARM64" />
<?endif?>
<Launch Condition="CpuArchitecture=TargetArchitecture" Message="!(loc.UnsupportedPlatformMessage)" />
<CustomAction Id="ResolveCpuArchitecture" Property="CpuArchitecture" Value="[%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE]" />
```

It looks rather ugly though, and I'm not even sure if it works as intended (ARM64 installer currently fails, I'm not sure why). Would anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QueryNativeMachine](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/reference/schema/util/querynativemachine/) to get the machine's architecture.

Comment: From my understanding, it's an extension which only works on Windows 10 version 1511 (TH2) and later. I'd like the installer to work on as old Windows as possible.

Although I guess I could check that the value returned matches `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_TARGET_HOST`, thus ensuring that no emulation is employed. I'll have a look, thanks.